# Rewrite rules defined on Azure application gateway does not seem to work on TRACE methods

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

I have defined a rewrite rule on my Azure application gateway that is rewriting a response header (Server=Unknown). I see that the rule is correctly executed on a GET, OPTIONS, DELETE method (returning either HTTP 200 or 405), however the rule does not seem to be fired on a TRACE method.
I wanted to address a finding from penetration tests that state that the server discloses technical information allowing an attacker to be informed of the reverse proxy installed.
Below is a screenshot of the HTTP DELETE method:

```
HTTP/1.1 405 
Date: Mon, 02 Nov 2020 14:47:18 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Cache-Control: no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Allow: GET
Server: Unknown
```

And below the same call using TRACE:

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Not Allowed
Server: Microsoft-Azure-Application-Gateway/v2
Date: Mon, 02 Nov 2020 14:47:50 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 183
Connection: close
```

Also to me the fact that the TRACE does not contain as many headers as the DELETE is a proof that the call will not reach the web server (which is fine with me) but then I expect the application gateway to fire the same rewrite rule as for any other method.

I also tried to remove the header instead of setting it to "Unknown" but this has the same effect (the header is removed on all methods except TRACE).

Answer (score 0):

Trace method is not yet added to the list. We have this in our road map but with no ETA. Please follow [Azure Updates page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/updates/) for further updates.

Comment: Almost 3 years later and after latest penetration tests the issue is still present... example of a GET call: `Server: Unknown` and example of a TRACE call: `Server: Microsoft-Azure-Application-Gateway/v2`. OWASP ZAP creates alert: Proxy Disclosure: Using the TRACE, OPTIONS, and TRACK methods, the following proxy servers have been identified between OWASP ZAP and the application/web server: 
- Microsoft-Azure-Application-Gateway/v2